# What is the chromatic number of S2?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, topological-graph-theory

How can one find the chromatic number of the orientable surface S2 (the double-torus)? Does anyone know of an example which shows this chromatic number by giving an upper bound and a lower bound?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_g$ be the orientable sphere with $g$ handles. Then its chromatic number $\chi(g)$ is given by the Heawood number
$$
h(S_g)=\left\lfloor \frac{7+\sqrt{1+48g}}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
for $g\le 1$. So $\chi(S_2)=8$.
For further details see for example [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=FCv6CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=chromatic+number+of+surface+S2&source=bl&ots=4j_6_0cmIW&sig=ACfU3U0rXvWvZjVvlOdCHXPWH6c6qH7jDg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR74KZxMnpAhUNxIUKHYsUB0AQ6AEwCnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=chromatic%20number%20of%20surface%20S2&f=false).

See also the wikipedia entry for [Heawood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_conjecture).

Comment: Is the Heawood number applicable only for orientable surfaces or even for non-orientable ? @Dietrich Burde

Comment: This is answered at wikipedia: "Replacing the genus by the Euler characteristic, we obtain a formula that covers both the orientable and non-orientable cases." Have a look!

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can show that chi(S_2)  <= 8 without using the Heawood conjecture? Would giving a drawing of K8 suffice? Thanks!

Comment: The proof of this upper bound is very short, see Theorem $7.28$ [here](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%207.PDF) for it.

Comment: is K_8 the graph which has maximum chromatic number over all graphs that are embeddable on genus 2? @Dietrich Burde? If yes, why so?

Comment: And thanks for your help always.